# Plot specific values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way to perform this. I've got a `df` with one `Column` containing information of interest. For the df below I'm interested in `Column B`. I want to create separate `plots` for each of `W,X,Y,Z` values. I'm also hoping to start each separate plot when these values change.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
    'A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,3],            
    'B' : ['W','W','X','X','Y','Y','Z','Z','W','W'], 
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So this df would display 4 different plots. There would 2 lines for the `W` value.

I'm currently exporting the above df into there own separate `series`. If I plot the values relating to `W` The output would be:

```
   W1  W2  X1  Y1  Z1
0   1   1   3   5   8
1   2   3   4   6   9

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(df['W1'])
plt.plot(df['W2'])
```

But this would mean I'm creating numerous separate `series` and `plots`. This wouldn't be very inefficient if my `df` contained 1000's of `rows` that continuously changed between values.

[image]
Is there an easier way? I think I'll still have to export each value to it's own series when the values change.

But I'm hoping there's an easier way to plot each series over the top of each each other without doing this.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your example, but doesn't your DataFrame look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/F2Fi63V)? How do you proceed to generate the columns W1 etc...?

Comment: Do you need plot for each group separately graph?

Comment: @jezrael that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need:

```
g = df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift()).cumsum()
df['C'] =  g.groupby(df['B']).transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).add(1).astype(str)
df['D'] = df.groupby(['B','C']).cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['D','C','B'])['A'].unstack([2,1])
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
print (df)
   W1  X1  Y1  Z1  W2
D                    
0   1   3   5   7   1
1   2   4   6   8   3

df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).plot()
```